# unable to find the error in code for quadratic equation

Tags: c, runtime-error

My friend asked to find error in this i am getting the real part of complex solution as zero.
can anyone tell me why and how to solve it,
thanks for your help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
    int i,a,b,c,d;
    float x,y;
    printf("ener the values for a,b,c");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a==0)
    {
        printf("not a quadratc equation");
    }
    else
    {
        d=(b*b-4*a*c);
        if(d==0)
        {
            printf("roots are equal");
            x=-b/(2*a);
            printf("\n%f\n%f",x,x);
        }
        else if(d>0)
        {
            x=(-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
            y=(-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a);
            printf("the roots are %f and %f",x,y);
        }
        else if(d<0)
        {
            x=-(b/(2*a));
            printf("%f",x);
            y=(sqrt(-d))/(2*a);
            printf("the roots are %f+i%f and %f-i%f",x,y,x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to learn how to format and indent your code, it's basically unreadable at the moment. After that learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line while checking values to see that everything is handled as you expect it to be.

Comment: Indent is very important . Go [here](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html)

Comment: Don't use float except in cases where memory is important. Use double instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing lots of math on `int` variables, and storing the result in `float`. That does *not* mean that the arithmetic is performed using floating point, it will all be integer.

The [`sqrt()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sqrt) returns `double`, so that saves the imaginary part. For the real part, all the math is integer, so `-(b / (2 * a))` will be evaluated using integers and then the final result will be stored in `x` as a float, of course without ever having any fractional part.

Comment: thanks,but i am getting the right answer for imaginary part

Comment: @user3499596 it's getting right because sqrt is double, which promote the other side of the `/` operator to double, and results in a floating-point divide. All other divisions (`-b/(2*a)`) are integer division.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is quite simple just change the code as below

```
else if(d<0)
    {
      x=(-((float)b/(2*(float)a)));    // type conversion to float from int
      printf("%f",x);
      y=(sqrt(-d))/(2*a);
      printf("the roots are %f+i%f and %f-i%f",x,y,x,y);
    }
```

The reason was, in quadratic equations complex root calculations if  real part is less than 1 (for eg 0.2) it is stored into variable x as integer (integer means only number w/o decimal part) , so you have to do type conversion to get the right data

Comment: it has bug in all cases that `b` cannot be fully divisible by `2a`

Comment: and just `b/(2.0f*a)` is enough, no need to cast

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc  You're right that also solves the problem

Comment: thanks,i will follow that